# How to Create New Macro in New File using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, module, save-as

I need to assign new macro to new Bottom in new File with VBA in Excel
In other words, I want to create a new file on pressing a button (run a macro) that contains a button that will run a predefined macro.

```
Sub Shapes()

'Shape 1 Test_Shape

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeBevel, 85.25, 0, 120, 30).Select

Selection.OnAction = "Macro1"

End sub 
'___________________________________________________________________________
Sub Macro1()

'For Example

Cells.Select

End Sub
```

Can anyone help me?

TNX

I searched many sites in English and Farsi, but I did not get a good result
As long as the file is not saved with a new name, everything is fine; But when I save the file with a new name, the macros no longer work (they are not transferred from the original file to the new file).

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer on Mr. Excel that can help you:
[Exporting module from workbook to workbook](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/exporting-module-from-workbook-to-workbook-not-working-user-specific.1217869/)

Here is the code, just adapt it to your specific needs

```
    'Copy macro from main file to extract
    Dim strModuleName As String
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim strTempFile As String
    ThisWorkbook.Activate              '<= changed
    strFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path      '<= changed
    If Len(strFolder) = 0 Then strFolder = CurDir
    strFolder = strFolder & "\"
    strTempFile = strFolder & "~tmpexport.bas"
    On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Alloc_Date_Button").Export strTempFile '<= changed
  
            'AMEND THE EXPORTED MACRO TO NEW NAME
            Dim objFSO
            Const ForReading = 1
            Const ForWriting = 2
            Dim objTS 'define a TextStream object
            Dim strContents As String
            Dim fileSpec As String
          
            fileSpec = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\~tmpexport.bas"
            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileSpec, ForReading)
            strContents = objTS.ReadAll
            strContents = Replace(strContents, "Alloc_Date_Button", "Alloc_Date_Button_Export")
            strContents = Replace(strContents, "ALLOC_DATE_UPDATE", "ALLOC_DATE_UPDATE_EXPORT")
          
            objTS.Close
          
            Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileSpec, ForWriting)
            objTS.Write strContents
            objTS.Close

  
    Output.VBProject.VBComponents.Import strTempFile '<= changed
    Kill strTempFile
    On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your response
I tried to use this code, but unfortunately I did not succeed
I know my knowledge about "VBA" is low and I am still not familiar with "Dim:" commands to find the problem. But I always try to update my information. I will be grateful if you write your answer with more additional explanation.
I remind you that my other problem is that I am not very fluent in English and I use a translator most of the time. So please understand me

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the suggested way was not useful for me. I solved my problem in another way. In my module, instead of putting the results in a new file, I put the information in a new sheet and at the end I deleted the extra sheets and saved the file with a new name. In this way, my problem was solved.
Thank you for your cooperation